# prove $\frac{\int f(x)dx \int g(x)dx}{b-a} \leq \int f(x)g(x)dx$ for all $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ over the interval [a,b]

Tags: calculus

I would like to prove that

$$\frac{\int f(x)dx \int g(x)dx}{b-a} \leq \int f(x)g(x)dx$$

using only first and second year calculus (as this is what I am familiar with).

I believe this is called Chebyshevís inequality but I looked it up on Wikipedia and found a very different looking theorem.

Thanks for the help

Comment: This is false without some additional assumptions on $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 2):

This inequality is not correct. Let $f(x) = \chi_{[0,1]} (x)$ and $g(x) = \chi_{(1,2]} (x)$ for $[a,b] = [0,2]$ (i.e. $f$ takes the value of $1$ from $0$ to $1$ and zero otherwise and $g$ takes the value $1$ on $1$ to $2$ and zero otherwise). Then $\int_0^2 f(x)dx = \int_0^2 g(x) dx = 1$, but $\int_0^2f(x)g(x)dx = 0$.

Comment: It's also easy to transform this into an example with smooth functions.

Comment: I found this inequality on a pdf, here's the link: http://www.sms.edu.pk/downloads/prceedingsfordae1/1_intinequal.pdf

Comment: Its is under theorem 1

Comment: did you mean that f and g are simultaneous increase or decrease?